# SBT unresolved dependency error for com.streamsend#pillar_2.10;1.0.3: not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am getting the below error while building my Play! framework Scala project in Intellij IDEA 15, the following is the error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.streamsend#pillar_2.10;1.0.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.streamsend#pillar_2.10;1.0.3: not found
```

Please help.

Comment: My build.sbt file contents are as under :

`name := "play2-scala-cassandra-sample"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.0.1",
  "com.streamsend" % "pillar_2.10" % "1.0.3"
)     

play.Project.playScalaSettings`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a newer version:
Replace:

```
"com.streamsend" % "pillar_2.10" % "1.0.3"
```

With:

```
"com.chrisomeara" % "pillar_2.10" % "2.0.1" (It's the same package but rebranded)
```

Comment: as of now I am facing a different issue in my application, which I have specified [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327242/com-impetus-kundera-query-queryhandlerexception-no-entity-found-by-the-name-e). Please have a look at this question and help me regarding this.